# Decode base64 string with quotes

Tags: python, base64, eol

`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\u003d\u003d
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`

When I try to store it in a variable in python, it doesn't work because it contains single and double quotes, so I get an EOL error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no quotes in your string; it's simply made up of two identical base64 encoded strings, each of which can be decoded fine after a small fix: it appears that what has happened is that the trailing `==` in the first string have become `\u003d\u003d`. Replace `\u003d\u003d` with `==` and use the first string, or just use the second string as is, and you're good.

I.e.,

```py
s1 = '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'
s2 = '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'

print(s1 == s2)  # True
print(base64.b64decode(s1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use triple quotes like so :

```
my_var = """My text with quotes ' " is stored in a variable this way"""
```

You could also use ''' instead of """ if you prefer.

```
my_var = '''My text with quotes ' " is also stored in a variable this way'''
```

See : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings